# When the k8s version will no longer be supported on GKE?

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine

I checked the following document and confirmed `validMasterVersions` and `validNodeVersions`. 
But I cannot confirm when the specified k8s version become unsupported from any documents.
I do not use release channels and specify k8s version by `static`.

I would like to know unsupported date about specified k8s version in advance.

ex.

```
Cluster 1.14.10 When unsupported on GKE?
Node 1.11.10 When unsupported on GKE?
```

Versioning and upgrades 
https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/versioning-and-upgrades

```
command:
＄ gcloud container get-server-config --zone asia-northeast1-c <br>

Cluster (Master): 1.14.10-gke.50 --- 1.17.12-gke.1501 
Node (Worker): 1.11.10-gke.6 --- 1.17.12-gke.1501
```

Also I check the following document, but it describe about using release channels.

Release notes
https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/release-notes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no document with that kind of information. The only thing close to your requirements is [Release Notes](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/release-notes) - No channel (no channel is static version). You would manually find information about specific version changes.

I've filled [Issue Report](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) in [Google Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com) to create that kind of document. You can track it by this link: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/172655091

Comment: Thank you for your prompt answer and filling the Issue Report.  
I check EOS of the specific version from no channel of Release Notes for a while.  EKS and AKS have the support calendar.
I hope GKE have the similar document.  
  
[Amazon EKS Kubernetes versions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/kubernetes-versions.html#kubernetes-release-calendar)  
[AKS Kubernetes Release Calendar](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/supported-kubernetes-versions#aks-kubernetes-release-calendar)  
  
I will track your report.